# Converting sql query to active record for selecting from multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlite

I am trying to find a way to convert sqlite3 query into active record format.

My query is:

```
SELECT first_name,last_name,title,checkin,checkout
FROM books, checkouthistories, users
WHERE checkouthistories.isbn = isbn and books.isbn = isbn AND
      checkouthistories.email = users.email`
```

I do know how to select from one table by using the `select` function and using the where clause, but I am not able to figure out a way to use multiple tables and multiple `where` clauses

Comment: Well, you got a few problems. 1) Which column in SELECT belongs to which table? 2) What are the relationships between the tables? 3) If you need to aggregate data from several tables, why not create a view, then select from the view through ActiveRecord?

Comment: First_name & last name are from user table, title from book table and checkin, checkout from checkouthisrory table.

Comment: OK, great. Now you have 2 questions to answer. 1) What are the relationships? 2) Have you looked into using a view?

Comment: @SrdjanPejic I havent considered using views. I am not sure how exactly I should use them especially in the context of ActiveRecords. Also for every email id in the user table, there will be multiple records in the checkouthistory table. Also for every isbn in the book table there will be multiple checkin, checkout values in the checkouthistory table

Comment: A view looks like a table to ActiveRecord, here's an example of how to do that, http://www.benfranklinlabs.com/tamed-monster-query-using-rails-activerecord-top-sql-view/.

Also, if there are actual relationships here, the solution @tim5046 provided would be a good starting point.

Comment: @SrdjanPejic I actually want to check both the isbn value to a specific variable, i.e books.isbn = isbn and checkouthistory.isbn = isbn , where isbn might be equal to some number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (I don't know exactly what your associations and models look like, so as you add more details I will update my answer):

```
Books.
joins("JOIN checkouthistories ON books.isbn = checkouthistories.isbn").
joins("JOIN users ON checkouthistories.email = users.email").
select("User.first_name, User.last_name, Book.title, Checkouthistory.checkin,Checkouthistory.checkout")
```